# Upstream DNS resolver not logging domain lookups

Tags: router, dns, pfsense, opendns

A `pfsense` router running `2.4.5-RELEASE-p1 (amd64)` software was originally configured to force the local network to only use `OpenDNS`.  In this configuration, `OpenDNS` logged all resolved domains, and it was possible to see a list of all resolved domains, or even just the blocked domains.

Later, `pfBlockerNG-devel 2.2.5_34` was installed on the router to augment DNS filtering capability, and to allow for more whitelist entries since `OpenDNS` allows only a small number of white/black list entries for free/inexpensive accounts.  (Categories would be de-listed at the `OpenDNS` level to let the `pfsense` router take them over and allow for additional white list size.)

The router was also configured to block all outbound DNS request from the local network, and to direct local clients to use the router's DNS resolver.  In this configuration, the goal of improving the DNS firewall was achieved (`pfblockerNG` logs show a large number of local device DNS requests are filtered).

It is acknowledged that it might be somewhat redundant to run `pfBlockerNG` downstream of `OpenDNS`, but a way of logging resolved domains was not readily apparent, so using `OpenDNS` to log the requests seemed like one way to see if unwelcome domains were still being resolved after the filtering was in place.

Unfortunately, though, after the `pfsense` configuration change, `OpenDNS` is no longer logging resolved domains despite being the upstream DNS resolver for the router.  (The configuration on `OpenDNS` did not change; logging is enabled.  `OpenDNS` still knows the router public IP.)

In the router, only `OpenDNS` IP addresses (208.67.222.222, 208.67.220.220) are listed in `System / General Setup / DNS Servers`.  There is only one WAN interface.  Other potentially relevant settings are:

```
DNS Server Override   [ ]
Allow DNS server list to be overridden by DHCP/PPP on WAN
If this option is set, pfSense will use DNS servers assigned by a DHCP/PPP server on WAN for its own purposes (including the DNS Forwarder/DNS Resolver). However, they will not be assigned to DHCP clients.

Disable DNS Forwarder [ ]
Do not use the DNS Forwarder/DNS Resolver as a DNS server for the firewall
By default localhost (127.0.0.1) will be used as the first DNS server where the DNS Forwarder or DNS Resolver is enabled and set to listen on localhost, so system can use the local DNS service to perform lookups. Checking this box omits localhost from the list of DNS servers in resolv.conf.
```

It seems that the router's requests to `OpenDNS` should be logged, but they are not, albeit with a few exceptions:

- Domains in the `Firewall > Aliases` are logged.
- The NTP server domain in the router configuration is logged.

Using `Diagnostics > DNS Lookup` confirms the router is using `OpenDNS` in the timings portion of the results.

What might need to be taken into consideration to understand why `OpenDNS` isn't logging the domains being resolved?  Is there a fundamental difference between local DNS resolving and the intermediate resolving done by the router?  It is recognized that the `pfsense` could be caching DNS, but the cache does have to be populated to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

Finding this `pfsense` forum post helped solve the problem:

[Can't seem to force OpenDNS](https://forum.netgate.com/topic/155916/can-t-seem-to-force-opendns)

```
Mr. Waste Aug 17, 2020, 5:26 PM

Go to:
Services/DNS Resolver/General Settings

Down to:
DNS Query Forwarding

Make sure its checked to be sent to those custom dns servers.
```

After checking this box, `OpenDNS` is logging domain look ups again.  It is still unclear [to me] how this changes the previous settings in a way that fixes logging, and seems counter-intuitive that it is required when DNS resolving appears to work fine without its being checked.  It seems that the other settings mentioned in the question should have assured use of `OpenDNS`, but perhaps they did not.